# C++ - how to improve this methods execution speed

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to improve my programming skills for an assignment that will be released soon, it involves solving a problem while making it run as efficient and as fast as possible. I know this is a fairly restrained/small piece of code but how if anything would make it run faster.

the method takes an array with holds details of transactions, there are 100 as the number of transactions used to maintain the loop. so  am getting the average num of shares and then returning it. not fluent english so hopefully it makes sense, thanks

```
double Analyser::averageVolume()
{
    // Your code
    double averageNumShares = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < nTransactions; i++)
    {
        averageNumShares += tArray[i].numShares;
    }
    averageNumShares = averageNumShares / nTransactions;
    return averageNumShares;
    //return 0
}
```

Comment: Well, you could compute the sum in parallel (using multithreading)...

Comment: What is tArray? A C++ array or a pointer to doubles?

Comment: It is a pointer, I should have included that, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to compute the average of n numbers I'm afraid that you can't speed it up much past the linear-time approch in your sample code..

Unless this is used as part of another more complex algorithm where you might be able to get away with not having to compute the average or something along these lines, taking an average is going to be an O(n) operation which basically involves summing all elements of the array and one division by the number of elements. Which is exactly what you have.

Comment: @Miky - You can achieve O(1) - See below.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have two other values for the object - A running total and the number of items?

Then computing the average can make use of those numbers. Quickly and simply (could be an inline function!).

Comment: BTW - The complexity for the average will be O(1) - A lot better than O(N)

Comment: @EdHeal - that's just shifting the sumation. It is O(1) only if invoked repeatedly for the same array. Otherwise it's still O(n) over-all.. Your solution is basically to cache the summation. You might as well cache the result of the division as well. Right?!

Comment: Ed has a point possibly: if the updates to the transactions are less frequent than the number of time we need the average, his approach could be better if size is also not an issue.  But likely there are many more transactions than times where you need to get the average number of transactions, in which case that alternate approach wouldn't be as good.

Comment: How much processing power is required to add/subtract to one number and increment/decrement another? BTW - Possibly the data structure for the array maintains one of those values (its size) so that could be a freebe.

Comment: @Milky - The point is that any time you want the average you do not need to go through the rig ma role of toting up the total. Consider adding one extra value - quick and simple to make an adjust to the total/size rather than recalculate the total again.

Comment: @MikyDinescu: Yes but... processors are very good at doing things in parallel when they are not interfering with each others. So doing the summation on its own is a bit hard because you keep modifying the `total` value (and there is nothing to parallelize this with) whilst keeping the `total` up-to-date as part of doing some bigger work might get completely transparent because it's parallelized with something that was already done anyway. On top of that, there is also the memory saving and the translation in potential cache misses savings.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one additional approach, similar to that suggested by [Ed Heal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15275919/1430833) that should be less sensitive to roundoff errors.  The roundoff error of the average grows with the size of the accumulated sum.  This may or may not be an issue for you, but it is something to be aware of.

Here is an iterative algorithm that minimizes roundoff error in the average, which I first came across in an old edition (circa 1998) of [Ross](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0125980574):

```
double Analyser::averageVolume()
{
  double averageNumShares = 0.0;

  for (int i = 0; i < nTransactions; i++)
  {
    double delta = (tArray[i].numShares - averageNumShares) / (i+1);
    averageNumShares += delta;
  }

  return averageNumShares;
}
```

This works by deriving a recursive definition of the average.  That is, given samples `x[1]`, ..., `x[j]`, ..., `x[N]`, you can calculate the average of the first `M+1` samples from sample `x[M+1]` and the average of the first `M` samples:

```
sum(M) = x[1] + x[2] + ... + x[M]
thus avg(M+1) = sum(M+1)/(M+1) and avg(M) = sum(M)/M

avg(M+1) - avg(M) = sum(M+1)/(M+1) - sum(M)/M
    = [ M*sum(M+1) - (M+1)*sum(M) ]/[ M * (M+1) ]
    = [ M*(x[M+1] + sum(M)) - M*sum(M) - sum(M) ] / [ M*(M+1) ]
    = [ M*x[M+1] - sum(M) ] / [ M*(M+1) ]
    = [ x[M+1] - avg(M) ] / (M+1)
thus: avg(M+1) = avg(M) + [ x[M+1] - avg(M) ]/(M+1)
```

To get a sense of the roundoff error for the two approaches, try computing the average of 10^7 samples, each sample equal to 1035.41.  Your original approach returns (on my hardware), an average of 1035.40999988683.  The iterative approach above returns the exact average of 1035.41.

Both, unfortunately, are O(N) at some point.  Your original scheme has N additions and one division.  The iterative scheme has N additions, subtractions, and divisions, so you pay a bit more for the accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

If you use gcc change level of optimization.

Comment: I might look into that, may be too advanced for me though lol

Comment: Indeed, you should be able to change optimization level with any compiler. @user2075995, adding `-O2` to your compile command line is too advanced? 8v)

Comment: I don't know what compiler you use but for gcc is most used.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
This code is as good as it gets with respect to speed.  What you can tweak is how you compile it.  Or obviously, rewrite it in assembly if that is an option.

"Stretched" answer:
Now... if you really want to try getting better performance, have already tried using all compiler optimization flags and optimizations available, and you are ready to compromise code readability for possibly more speed, you *could* consider rewriting:

```
for(int i = 0; i < nTransactions; i++)
    {
        averageNumShares += tArray[i].numShares;
    }
```

as

```
pointerValue = &(tArray[0].numShares);
pointerIncrement = sizeof(tArray[0]);
for(int i = 0; i < nTransactions; i++)
    {
        averageNumShares += *(pointerValue++pointerIncrement);
    }
```

It could be that you get better performance by showing the compiler all you do is jump over a fixed offset at each loop iteration.  A good compiler should be able to see that with your initial code.  And the new code could get your worse performance.  It really depends on the specifics of your compiler, and again, I do not recommend that approach unless you are desperate for better performance than what the compiler can offer, and don't want to jump to using in-line assembly or intrinsics (if any available).

Comment: Thanks I appreciate all the feedback on this

Answer (score 0):

```
int i= nTransactions;
while(i--){// test for 0 is faster
    averageNumShares += (q++)->numShares;// increment pointer is faster than offset
}
```